# Упорядоченный список матриц по количеству единиц

Tags: c#, linq

Прошу помощи в решении. Имеется класс булева матрица. Нужно вывести упорядоченный список матриц по количеству единиц с помощью *LINQ*.

```
class BoolMatrix
{
    private bool[][] arr;

    public BoolMatrix()
    {
        arr = new bool[2][];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = new bool[2];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Введите матрицу");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
            {

                String s = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (s)
                {
                    case "0":
                        {
                            arr[i][j] = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            arr[i][j] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int CountOfUnit()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j]) c++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: И что не получается? `OrderBy` должен прекрасно сработать

Comment: Я не понимаю как вывести список. Т.е, допустим, я создам объекты matrix_1 и matrix_2, и как в таком случае мне вывести отсортированный список из имен этих объектов ?

Comment: Из "Имен"? А как вы храните имена? В вашем коде я этого не вижу

Comment: А как Вы видите это задание ? К примеру, если дописать к класс метод вывода матрицы на консоль, как тогда в результате работы linq выводить матрицы в отсортированном порядке ?

Comment: `foreach (var bm in list.OrderBy(m => m.CountOfUnit())) bm.Print()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, разобрался сам. Сможете помочь с други заданием ? Нужно выбрать матрицы с равным количеством true(1) в
каждой строке.
Пока такое, дальше не знаю, что делать:
var findSymbolRequest = from item in list
      where item.CountOfUnit != 0
      select item;

Comment: Задайте вопрос отдельным топиком

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (var bm in list.OrderBy(m => m.CountOfUnit())) bm.Print()
```